# How can i rewrite this methods without duplication?

Tags: java, jdbc, dao

How can make this code without duplication? 
This methods are similar.

Method to create phone Numbers:

```
   private List<String> createPhoneNumbers(String sqlStatement, Long id) {
        List<String> phones = new ArrayList<>();
        try (PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement)) {
            statement.setLong(1, id);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    phones.add(resultSet.getString("phoneNumber"));
                }
                return phones;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Method to create friend list:

```
   private List<Account> createFriendList(String sqlStatement, Long id) {
        List<Account> friends = new ArrayList<>();
        try (PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement)) {
            statement.setLong(1, id);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    friends.add(createSimpleElement(resultSet));
                }
                return friends;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Method to create group list:

```
   private List<Group> createGroupList(String sqlStatement, Long id) {
        List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        try (PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement)) {
            statement.setLong(1, id);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    groups.add(createGroupFromResultSet(resultSet));
                }
                return groups;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is my very bad solution.

```
 //field values: 1- create String, 2 - createAccount, 3 - createGroup
private <E> List<E> createList(String selectSql, Long id, int field) {
    List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement(selectSql)) {
        statement.setLong(1, id);
        try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                switch (field) {
                    case 1:
                        list.add((E) resultSet.getString("phoneNumber"));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        list.add((E) createSimpleElement(resultSet));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        list.add((E) createGroupFromResultSet(resultSet));
                        break;
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

What can I read to solve similar problems in my code?

Comment: Don't. It's good practise to have methods that just do one thing and do it well. And if needed you can always use interfaces or abstract classes.

Comment: u can read on design patterns and try them 
out by writing code, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you should check out [Spring JDBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) and it's callback-based [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) approach. It abstracts all the boilerplate (database connections, transactions, exception translation etc.) away from you and lets you focus on application code.

Sample:

```
List<Actor> actors = this.jdbcTemplate.query(
        "select first_name, last_name from t_actor",
        new RowMapper<Actor>() {
            public Actor mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Actor actor = new Actor();
                actor.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
                actor.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
                return actor;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

"Separate what changes from what stays same" - Head First Design Pattern.

You can separate the logic to extract data from Resultset (which changes) from preparing the statement and executing the statement (which does not change)

You can do something like below in case you do not want to take help from any framework support

```
public interface GenericDao {
    ResultSet find(String sqlStatement, Long id);
}

public class GenericDaoImpl extends GenericDao {
    @Override
    public ResultSet find(String sqlStatement, Long id) {
        try (PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement)) {
            statement.setLong(1, id);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                return resultSet;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public interface ContactDao {
    List<String> createPhoneNumbers(String sqlStatement, Long id);
    List<Account> createFriendList(String sqlStatement, Long id);
    List<Group> createGroupList(String sqlStatement, Long id);
}

public class ContactDaoImpl extends ContactDao{
    private GenericDao genericDao;

    ContactDaoImpl(GenericDao genericDao) {
        this.genericDao = genericDao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> createPhoneNumbers(String sqlStatement, Long id) {
        ResultSet resultSet = this.genericDao.executeSqlQuery(sqlStatement, id);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            phones.add(resultSet.getString("phoneNumber"));
        }
        return phones;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Account> createFriendList(String sqlStatement, Long id) {
        ResultSet resultSet = this.genericDao.executeSqlQuery(sqlStatement, id);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            friends.add(createSimpleElement(resultSet));
        }
        return friends;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Group> createGroupList(String sqlStatement, Long id) {
        ResultSet resultSet = this.genericDao.executeSqlQuery(sqlStatement, id);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            groups.add(createGroupFromResultSet(resultSet));
        }
        return groups;
    }
}
```